# Making number and solid bullets with delphi xe5 and MS Word

Tags: vba, delphi, ms-word

I need to create a numbered bullet with text and then a sub-list under the first bullet(which is solid bullet style- black circle bullets).

I recorded this but the bullet creation is so confusing I cannot make sense of it.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
    With ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = "%1."
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior
    Selection.TypeText Text:="hey ajsdhakjsdh"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below compiles and runs for me using D7 + MS Word2007.

A couple of caveats:

- As I haven't got Word2010 installed and so can't test with it, there are two lines in the call to ApplyListTemplateWithLevel which are commented out.  If you have Word2010, you can, of course, reinstate them.
- MS Word's InchesToPoints method doesn't work when called via Ole Automation, so the code below does its own inches->points conversion.

**Update:**  I've updated the code below so that it's behaviour can be controlled by a checkbox named cbUseBullets.  If this is checked, you get bullets and sub-bullets.  If it isn't, it selects one of the predefined multilevel list styles and uses that.  The style is selected by the line:

```
Template := Gallery.ListTemplates.Item(4);
```

In Word 2007 at any rate, Item(4) is the one that does this:

```
Article I.  hey 
Section 1.01    Blah
```

Doing a custom multi-level list is "left as an exercise to the reader".  The way to do it would be to record a Word macro that sets it up how you want, and then "just" translate it into Delphi - hopefully the code below will show you the way into that.

Code:

```
const
  CmToPostScriptPoints : Single = 28.3464567;
  InsToPostScriptPoints : Single = 72;
  InchesToCm : Single = 2.54;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MSWord : OleVariant;
  Document,
  Galleries,
  Gallery,
  Templates,
  Template,
  Levels,
  Level,
  Afont : OleVariant;
begin
  try
    MsWord := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');
  except
    try
      MsWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
      MsWord.Visible := True;
    except
      Exception.Create('Error');
    end;
  end;
  Document := MSWord.Documents.Add;

  Galleries := MSWord.ListGalleries;

  try
    if cbUseBullets.Checked then begin
      Templates := Document.ListTemplates;
      Template := Templates.Add;
      Levels := Template.ListLevels;
      Level := Levels.Item(1);
      Level.NumberFormat := '•';
      Level.TrailingCharacter := wdTrailingTab;
      Level.NumberStyle := wdListNumberStyleBullet;
      Level.NumberPosition := CmToPostScriptPoints * 0.63;
      Level.Alignment := wdListLevelAlignLeft;
      Level.TextPosition := CmToPostScriptPoints * 1.27;
      Level.TabPosition := wdUndefined;
      Level.ResetOnHigher := 0;
      Level.StartAt := 1;
    end
    else begin
      Gallery := Galleries.Item(wdListGalleryType(wdOutlineNumberGallery));
      Template := Gallery.ListTemplates.Item(4);
      Levels := Template.ListLevels;
      Level := Levels.Item(1);
    end;

    Afont := Level.Font;
    // Change any font properties here

    Level.LinkedStyle := '';
    Template.Name := '';

    MSWord.Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel(
       ListTemplate := Template,
       ContinuePreviousList := False,
       ApplyTo := wdListApplyToWholeList
       //,
       //DefaultListBehavior:= wdWord10ListBehavior
    );

    MSWord.Selection.TypeText(Text:= 'hey ajsdhakjsdh');
    MSWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs('D:\doc2.doc');
  except
    Document.Close(False);
    Close;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try to figure out how this is going to work... Will get back to you asap:)

Comment: I've updated the comments and code to show how to selectively use bullets or one of the predefined multi-level list styles.